# Netbeans Remote Debug C++ No Console Output

Tags: c++, debugging, netbeans, console

Netbeans 8.2 on Windows 10

Remote C/C++ Build Host is Raspberry Pi 3

Simple C++ program with printf or cout to display output to console

Console output appears fine when program is run

No console output is displayed if run with debug option

Tried all 3 settings:

Project Properties + Run + Console Type:

```
Internal Terminal, Standard Terminal, External Terminal
```

How can I see console output when debugging remote program?

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved, add following line to beginning of program.

setbuf(stdout, NULL);   // disable buffering on stdout

Right Click on the project name > Properties > Categories > "Run" and set Console Type = "Standard Output".

Comment: `setbuf(stdout, NULL);` is not needed for my project but the "Standart Output" setting is the key